# Reference a windows uwp sdk inside a net5 windows app

Tags: winforms, uwp, reference, sdk, .net-5

I have to use a SDK that targets uap10.0.x from a windows application.

I have tried adding Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts and Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT but it gives build error Failed CLR.

I did some research and discovered a way to add uap in TargetFrameworks.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/net-core-cross-target-with-uap/174053

After I did this, I got errors for Windows.Forms and other libraries.

I also tried creating a .net standard library and add the reference there. The build was successful but I got runtime error for Platform not supported when using the library inside the net5.0 app.

I also tried creating compilation constants to only use the library in windows os but the error was the same.

What is the way to go in this case? Is it possible to use a uwp library inside windows app or should I create a uwp project and find a way to start it from the windows app.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a uwp library inside windows app ...

No, if the SDK only targets the **uap10.0** target framework moniker (TFM), you cannot use it in an app that targets any other framework than UWP.

A TFM, such as for example **uap10** or **netstandard2.0,** specifies a set of APIs that are available to the library or app. If you want to be able use the SDK from both UWP and .NET apps, it should target .NET Standard.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information about target frameworks and TFMs.

Comment: The problem is that the sdk comes from a 3rd party supplier and I can't modify it to target net standard. Right now I created a separate uwp to use it and I'm trying to open it from the windows app since this sdk will be used only if a certain criteria is met. Do you know if it's possible to install a uwp in customer device without putting in on windows store?

Comment: If the 3rd party doesn't provide another target than uap10.0, they don't support anything else than UWP.

Comment: You can sideload UWP app onto devices without using the Store but that's another question.